# How to use Escape sequences in JAVA

Tags: java, escaping

Hi I am having issues with this JAVA class. I know this is simple stuff but it just isn't working for me.

The code I have so far is this:

```
    public class ShowEscapeSequences {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("I really like \n\t\"CIS355A\"Business Application Programming with Lab using JAVA\"");
    }//End of main
}
```

and it gives this output:

```
 I really like 


    "CIS355A"Business Application Programming with Lab using JAVA"
```

But I need the output to look like this:

```
I really like

    CIS355A 
         "Business Application Programming with Lab using JAVA"
```

How do I do this without generating 100 errors?

Comment: Just *try* with `\n` and `\t`.

Comment: Ok, now I'm not sure what the desired string is after the edit...

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

Your string needs to be

```
"I really like\n\n\tCIS355A \n\t\t \"Business Application Programming with Lab using JAVA\""
```

This is based on looking at the raw text in the question.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. If this was the answer, go ahead and mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print("I really like\n\n\tCIS355A \n\t\t\ "Business Application Programming with Lab using JAVA\"");
```

Comment: Look closely and you'll see there's an extra space after CIS355A and there are 2 tabs and a space before "Business (9 total spaces).